# Java OpenPdf - Find special character in pdf : U+FB01

Tags: pdf, char, special-characters, openpdf

I need to find the character [ﬁ](https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+FB01) : `<span>&#64257;</span>` inside of a pdf that's causing a bug with **PdfBox** when I try to read it in java.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+FB01 ('fi') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding
```

In this case adding the font is not an option. We prefer to find the character and replace it with something else.

The problem is that I cannot find the character with normal tools like adobe reader or even word.

So I wrote a program in java that reads char by char and gets its unicode and compares it to the unicode that I'm looking for *U+FB01*.

But I cannot find it. Can you please tell me if there is something wrong with my code or if there is any other way to find the character.

Here is the fiddle to my program: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/kaD

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Charset encoding = Charset.defaultCharset();
        File file = new File(Main.class.getResource("spec.pdf").getFile());
        handleFile(file, encoding);
    }

    private static void handleFile(File file, Charset encoding)
            throws IOException {
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
             Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);
             // buffer for efficiency
             Reader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
            handleCharacters(buffer);
        }
    }

    private static void handleCharacters(Reader reader)
            throws IOException {
        int r;
        while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) r;
            String unicode = getUnicodeValue(ch);
            if(unicode.equals("\uFB01")){
                System.out.println(ch);
            }
            System.out.println(unicode);
        }
    }

    private static String getUnicodeValue(char c){
        return  "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(c | 0x10000).substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: PDFBox shouldn't fail with IllegalArgumentException when reading / displaying PDFs, only when creating them. Are you using the latest version (2.0.24)? Can you share the PDF or is it confidential?

Comment: The character code in the PDF object which draws the text is not, in general, a Unicode code point. It may be the same value as the Unicode code for that character but it's not Unicode. If the font has an associated ToUnicode CMap then a Unicode code point is available for every character code listed in that map. However even then the Unicode value may not be 0xFB01, it  is permissible to describe an fi ligature as 'f' and 'i', so the ToUnicode CMap would contain <0066> <0069>. Without seeing your PDF file I can't tell whether it is even possible to get Unicode values.

Comment: You could try to inspect your file with PDFDebugger (or RUPS) but it requires some knowledge how fonts are used. Your current code reads the PDF as if this is some "human readable" format like HTML, but it isn't.

Comment: Unfortunately the pdf file is confidential, I cannot share it :(

Comment: I am actually using implementation("org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-itext5:9.1.16")

Comment: itext isn't PDFBox. You could use the command line application of PDFBox to try ExtractText on the file to see if you get anything useful.

Comment: thank you I will try that, and I will post the results.

Comment: Please show the pivotal code where the issue occurs. Furthermore, you mention OpenPdf, PDFBox, and iText. Which library do you use in the code that throws the error? Also the error does not sound like it occurs while you _read_ a PDF but while you _add new content_ to it. Please clarify.